# Debian: set a command to be "always up" (and restart when updated)

Tags: debian, daemon

Suppose I have a REST API defined in:

```
rest-api.py
```

Which I would like to make 'always up':

```
setsid rest-api.py 2>&1 > /var/rest-api/log.0
logrotate rest-api.conf

# now: command to watch rest-api.py for failure and re-up
```

Next, what I would like to do is re-up the code the second the write timestamp is modified (i.e., when I save a change).  How would I do that?

I know that I could use `make`and `cron`, but is that the best way?

Comment: I didn't get completely what you're asking, but tools like [`inotifywait`](https://manpages.debian.org/inotify-tools/inotifywait.1) (and underlying API) can monitor file changes and be used for event loops.

Comment: @A.B so `setsid inotify_wait_script.sh` which chains itself?

Comment: I mean that instead of polling some check in cron once per minute, inotifywait -m could be used to push an event to whatever it's piped to whenever a specific file (or directory etc) was written to.

Comment: When you say "_always up_" and "_re-up_" I think you mean _always running_ and _restart_. Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by "_watch rest-api.py for failure_"? That sounds like you simply want to wait until it stops running. But you also say that you want to "_re-up (restart?) the code the second the write timestamp is modified_". Which is it you want? And if it's the second, what file do you want to watch?

Answer (score 0):

```
inotifywait -e modify rest-api.py
```

With a few other details to get everything running:

```
rest_api=$(pwd)/rest-api.py
rest_api_conf=$(pwd)/rest-api.conf
rest_api_log=/var/log/rest-api/rest-api.log

# log
mkdir -p /var/log/rest-api
logrotate $rest_api_conf

# daemon
setsid $rest_api 2>&1 >> $rest_api_log &
pid=$!
trap "kill $pid" exit

while true; do
  inotifywait -e modify $rest_api
  kill $pid
  setsid $rest_api 2>&1 >> $rest_api_log &
  pid=$!
  trap "kill $pid" exit
done
```

Finally, run as a background process or daemon:

```
./rest-api.sh &
setsid ./rest-api.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null
```